# ScrollView transparent background Android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have an Horizontal Scrollview which contain images and i would like to make the background of the cell transparent. The goal is to only see the images over the background.
After setting the background color in the ScrollView to transparent, the background of the cell is Grey light.

Do you know how could i solve it ?

**EDIT:**
The problem was my images in my scrollView, i finally applied a transparent background to the ImageView in my ScrollView with:

ImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Also i needed to add the transparent background (in XML) in ScrollView with:

```
<ScrollView
  ..
   android:background="#00FFFFFF";
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Which color do you set to your main layout of the activity?

Comment: @JoséMª The background of my main layout is a wood Texture, i solved the problem. The problem was my ImageView in the ScrollView,  i applied a transparent background to these images and it works. Everything is transparent apart the images:)